# Create an array of paths in Bash

Tags: bash

I need to create a script to perform a CLI command inside each sub directory
Imagine I've the main direct and inside 3 sub-directories.
I need to loop in each sub-directories and perform an action

In PHP I wilt try something like

```
foreach( $paths as $path){
   //do something
}
```

My full script (from comment)

```sh
#!/bin/bash 

path=/home/sebastien/projets/XXXX/customers/Sites/ 
today=$(date +%s) 

for d in $path; do 
  [ -L "${d%/}" ] && continue
  echo "$d" 
  orig=$(stat -c %y ${d} ) 
  epoch=$(date -d "${orig}" +"%s") 
  diff=$(($today-$epoch)) 
  jour=$(($diff/86400)) 
  echo $jour 
  if [ "$jour" -ge 4 ] then 
    cd $d #lando rebuild --y
  fi
done
```

How to perform this in bash script please ?

Comment: `I wilt try something like` How wil that iterate over subdirectories of a directory?

Comment: `path` above is a single directory. See answers below using either `for d in */; do` or `for d in **/; do` (after setting `globstar`)

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like

```sh
paths=(dir1 dir2)
for path in "${paths[@]}"
do
    echo "$path"
done
```

Comment: Thank you @Nabil but in this case, how to determine PATHS automatically ?
I mean in my case dir1 and dir2 are my subfolders but I will add this script in a cron job and subfolder names are unknown when I create the script.

Comment: You create an  empty array then append the value then do a for loop. [Array in bash](https://opensource.com/article/18/5/you-dont-know-bash-intro-bash-arrays)

Comment: if you want the directory of all csv files you can `declare -a dirs=($(find -name "*.csv"))`  then you can for loop iterate on the array

Answer (score 1):

> I need to loop in each sub-directories and perform an action

Then do that.

```
for i in */; do
  action "$i"
done
```

Comment: My full script is
```
#!/bin/bash
path=/home/sebastien/projets/XXXX/customers/Sites/
today=$(date +%s)

for d in $path ; do
    [ -L "${d%/}" ] && continue
    echo "$d"
    orig=$(stat -c %y ${d} )
    epoch=$(date -d "${orig}" +"%s")
    diff=$(($today-$epoch))
    jour=$(($diff/86400))
    echo $jour
    if [ "$jour" -ge 4 ]
    then
    cd $d
    #lando rebuild --y
    fi
done
```
result is :
```
$ sh destroy-lando.sh 
/home/sebastien/projets/XXXX/customers/Sites/
6
~/Bureau$
```
SOrry for code format, I can't succeed to get it clean....

Comment: You want to add `current=$PWD` to save current directory and then after `cd "$d" #lando rebuild --y` (added double quotes) add `cd "$current"` as the next line to change back to the working directory.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU bash version >= 4.0:

```
# Enable globstar feature
shopt -s globstar

# glob for all directories recursive and remove trailing /
for dir in **/; do echo "${dir/%\//}"; done

# Disable globstar feature
shopt -u globstar
```

See: `man bash`

Comment: Here is the script:
```
#!/bin/bash
path=/home/sebastien/projets/customers/Sites/


# Enable globstar feature
shopt -s globstar

# glob for all directories recursive and remove trailing /
for dir in $path;
do echo "${dir/%\//}";
done

# Disable globstar feature
shopt -u globstar
```
Inside "Sites", I've 2 subdirectory, but the result is
$ bash destroy-lando.sh 
/home/sebastien/projets/customers/Sites
/home/sebastien/projets/customers/Sites/
$

Comment: for the trailing `/`: `"${dir%/}"`